# Пожалуйста подскажите что это?

Tags: файлы

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

Comment: Судя по добивке знаками `=`, могу предположить, что это данные, закодированные в `base64`. Возможно, фотография.

Answer (score 1):

Это данные закодированные в BASE64. Декодинг даёт json:

```
   {"lastPlayed":"2021/01/02 01:09:08","chunkWidth":2,"chunkHeight":9,"mapChunks":[0,0,3,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0],"groundTilesWidth":21,"groundTilesHeight":98,"groundTiles":[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,8,8,8,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,8,8,8,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,9,8,8,8,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,2,8,8,8,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,9,2,10,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,7,7,7,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,10,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,2,0,2,10,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,0,0,2,10,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,6,6,6,6,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,0,2,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,2,10,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],"areasUnlocked":[false,true,false],"gameDays":8,"todaysEvent":4,"currentDayTime":25.00444793701172,"snowValue":0.0,"rainValue":0.0,"placedBuildingsData":[{"id":0,"type":0,"x":5,"y":42,"rotation":0.0,"currentHealth":100,"currentLevel":0,"currentCompletion":54,"currentlyStoredResources":[4],"isPaused":false,"craftableItemsList":[],"carftableItemData":[],"addedResourceQuantity":[],"nextRequiredResource":0,"currentProgress":0,"currentStored":0},{"id":1,"type":23,"x":11,"y":42,"rotation":0.0,"currentHealth":200,"currentLevel":0,"currentCompletion":102,"currentlyStoredResources":[10],"isPaused":false,"craftableItemsList":[],"carftableItemData":[],"addedResourceQuantity":[0,2,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"nextRequiredResource":0,"currentProgress":0,"currentStored":0},{"id":2,"type":4,"x":11,"y":39,"rotation":0.0,"currentHealth":400,"currentLevel":0,"currentCompletion":202,"currentlyStoredResources":[15],"isPaused":false,"craftableItemsList":[],"carftableItemData":[],"addedResourceQuantity":[79,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"nextRequiredResource":0,"currentProgress":0,"currentStored":0},{"id":3,"type":4,"x":11,"y":37,"rotation":0.0,"currentHealth":400,"currentLevel":0,"currentCompletion":0,"currentlyStoredResources":[2],"isPaused":true,"craftableItemsList":[],"carftableItemData":[],"addedResourceQuantity":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"nextRequiredResource":0,"currentProgress":0,"currentStored":0},{"id":4,"type":5,"x":8,"y":46,"rotation":0.0,"currentHealth":600,"currentLevel":0,"currentCompletion":301,"currentlyStoredResources":[10],"isPaused":false,"craftableItemsList":[],"carftableItemData":[],"addedResourceQuantity":[],"nextRequiredResource":0,"currentProgress":0,"currentStored":0},{"id":5,"type":3,"x":11,"y":45,"rotation":0.0,"currentHealth":600,"currentLevel":0,"currentCompletion":0,"currentlyStoredResources":[4],"isPaused":false,"craftableItemsList":[1,3],"carftableItemData":[{"currentQuantity":0,"capacity":0,"isBeingCrafted":false,"currentProgress":0.0,"currentlyStored":[0]},{"currentQuantity":0,"capacity":0,"isBeingCrafted":false,"currentProgress":0.0,"currentlyStored":[0]}],"addedResourceQuantity":[],"nextRequiredResource":0,"currentProgress":0,"currentStored":0},{"id":6,"type":5,"x":18,"y":35,"rotation":90.0,"currentHealth":600,"currentLevel":0,"currentCompletion":300,"currentlyStoredResources":[10],"isPaused":false,"craftableItemsList":[],"carftableItemData":[],"addedResourceQuantity":[],"nextRequiredResource":0,"currentProgress":0,"currentStored":0},{"id":7,"type":5,"x":18,"y":37,"rotation":90.0,"currentHealth":600,"currentLevel":0,"currentCompletion":301,"currentlyStoredResources":[10],"isPaused":false,"craftableItemsList":[],"carftableItemData":[],"addedResourceQuantity":[],"nextRequiredResource":0,"currentProgress":0,"currentStored":0},{"id":8,"type":25,"x":14,"y":37,"rotation":0.0,"currentHealth":600,"currentLevel":0,"currentCompletion":303,"currentlyStoredResources":[20],"isPaused":false,"craftableItemsList":[],"carftableItemData":[],"addedResourceQuantity":[],"nextRequiredResource":0,"currentProgress":7,"currentStored":0}],"newSpawn":[{"previousX":6,"previousY":42,"currentX":6,"currentY":42,"isVisible":true,"myJob":0,"isExecutingAction":false,"currentActionType":15,"myName":"Yuta","myType":0,"assignedHomeId":-1,"assignedWorkshopId":-1,"isMale":true,"hasHair":true,"bodyType":2,"hairType":0,"upperType":2,"facialHairType":2,"strength":1,"agility":1,"intelligence":3,"experience":1,"learnedSkills":[11],"currentStomachFill":4,"myEnergy":5,"myHealth":130,"maxHealth":130,"walkSpeed":1.9748921394348145,"bleeding":0.0,"burning":0.0,"poisoned":0.0,"carriedType":3,"carryQuantity":0,"hasItemInSlot":[false,false,false,false],"itemInSlot":[0,0,0,0]}],"workers":[{"previousX":12,"previousY":40,"currentX":12,"currentY":40,"isVisible":true,"myJob":1,"isExecutingAction":true,"currentActionType":4,"myName":"Asav","myType":0,"assignedHomeId":6,"assignedWorkshopId":2,"isMale":true,"hasHair":true,"bodyType":0,"hairType":0,"upperType":4,"facialHairType":2,"strength":3,"agility":1,"intelligence":2,"experience":43,"learnedSkills":[8],"currentStomachFill":4,"myEnergy":5,"myHealth":130,"maxHealth":130,"walkSpeed":1.8777880668640137,"bleeding":0.0,"burning":0.0,"poisoned":0.0,"carriedType":0,"carryQuantity":0,"hasItemInSlot":[false,false,false,false],"itemInSlot":[0,0,0,0]},{"previousX":16,"previousY":42,"currentX":16,"currentY":42,"isVisible":true,"myJob":1,"isExecutingAction":true,"currentActionType":0,"myName":"Mian","myType":0,"assignedHomeId":6,"assignedWorkshopId":2,"isMale":true,"hasHair":true,"bodyType":2,"hairType":3,"upperType":6,"facialHairType":0,"strength":3,"agility":1,"intelligence":1,"experience":152,"learnedSkills":[0],"currentStomachFill":4,"myEnergy":5,"myHealth":130,"maxHealth":130,"walkSpeed":1.5723023414611817,"bleeding":0.0,"burning":0.0,"poisoned":0.0,"carriedType":0,"carryQuantity":0,"hasItemInSlot":[false,false,false,false],"itemInSlot":[0,0,0,0]},{"previousX":6,"previousY":42,"currentX":6,"currentY":42,"isVisible":true,"myJob":5,"isExecutingAction":true,"currentActionType":11,"myName":"Zian","myType":0,"assignedHomeId":-1,"assignedWorkshopId":0,"isMale":true,"hasHair":false,"bodyType":0,"hairType":2,"upperType":1,"facialHairType":1,"strength":3,"agility":1,"intelligence":1,"experience":73,"learnedSkills":[7],"currentStomachFill":3,"myEnergy":3,"myHealth":78,"maxHealth":130,"walkSpeed":1.6578545570373536,"bleeding":0.0,"burning":0.0,"poisoned":0.0,"carriedType":7,"carryQuantity":0,"hasItemInSlot":[false,true,false,false],"itemInSlot":[0,0,0,0]},{"previousX":9,"previousY":46,"currentX":9,"currentY":46,"isVisible":false,"myJob":5,"isExecutingAction":true,"currentActionType":6,"myName":"Ziru","myType":0,"assignedHomeId":4,"assignedWorkshopId":0,"isMale":false,"hasHair":true,"bodyType":2,"hairType":0,"upperType":6,"facialHairType":0,"strength":4,"agility":1,"intelligence":1,"experience":4,"learnedSkills":[3],"currentStomachFill":4,"myEnergy":3,"myHealth":130,"maxHealth":130,"walkSpeed":1.9152069091796876,"bleeding":0.0,"burning":0.0,"poisoned":0.0,"carriedType":7,"carryQuantity":0,"hasItemInSlot":[false,true,false,false],"itemInSlot":[0,0,0,0]},{"previousX":18,"previousY":45,"currentX":18,"currentY":45,"isVisible":true,"myJob":16,"isExecutingAction":true,"currentActionType":4,"myName":"Surek","myType":0,"assignedHomeId":7,"assignedWorkshopId":1,"isMale":true,"hasHair":true,"bodyType":1,"hairType":2,"upperType":5,"facialHairType":2,"strength":1,"agility":3,"intelligence":1,"experience":130,"learnedSkills":[2],"currentStomachFill":4,"myEnergy":5,"myHealth":45,"maxHealth":130,"walkSpeed":1.5390784740447999,"bleeding":54.0,"burning":0.0,"poisoned":0.0,"carriedType":1,"carryQuantity":1,"hasItemInSlot":[false,false,false,false],"itemInSlot":[0,0,0,0]},{"previousX":14,"previousY":40,"currentX":14,"currentY":40,"isVisible":true,"myJob":19,"isExecutingAction":true,"currentActionType":9,"myName":"Ximi","myType":0,"assignedHomeId":4,"assignedWorkshopId":8,"isMale":false,"hasHair":true,"bodyType":0,"hairType":2,"upperType":4,"facialHairType":0,"strength":1,"agility":1,"intelligence":3,"experience":71,"learnedSkills":[4],"currentStomachFill":4,"myEnergy":5,"myHealth":130,"maxHealth":130,"walkSpeed":2.434156894683838,"bleeding":0.0,"burning":0.0,"poisoned":0.0,"carriedType":1,"carryQuantity":0,"hasItemInSlot":[false,false,false,false],"itemInSlot":[0,0,0,0]},{"previousX":14,"previousY":40,"currentX":14,"currentY":40,"isVisible":true,"myJob":19,"isExecutingAction":true,"currentActionType":9,"myName":"Ason","myType":0,"assignedHomeId":7,"assignedWorkshopId":8,"isMale":true,"hasHair":true,"bodyType":2,"hairType":0,"upperType":2,"facialHairType":2,"strength":1,"agility":3,"intelligence":1,"experience":43,"learnedSkills":[7],"currentStomachFill":4,"myEnergy":5,"myHealth":130,"maxHealth":130,"walkSpeed":1.847425937652588,"bleeding":0.0,"burning":0.0,"poisoned":0.0,"carriedType":1,"carryQuantity":0,"hasItemInSlot":[false,false,false,false],"itemInSlot":[0,0,0,0]}],"thieves":[],"possessed":[],"spawnTonight":2,"attackingMonsters":[],"spawnToday":4,"roamingAnimals":[],"workerCorpse":[],"monsterCorpse":[],"theifCorpse":[],"possessedCorpse":[],"animalCorpse":[{"previousX":18,"previousY":46,"currentX":18,"currentY":46,"isVisible":true,"myJob":0,"isExecutingAction":false,"currentActionType":24,"myName":"Boar","myType":4,"assignedHomeId":-1,"assignedWorkshopId":-1,"isMale":false,"hasHair":false,"bodyType":0,"hairType":0,"upperType":0,"facialHairType":0,"strength":1,"agility":1,"intelligence":-1,"experience":0,"learnedSkills":[],"currentStomachFill":4,"myEnergy":5,"myHealth":0,"maxHealth":60,"walkSpeed":1.3965840339660645,"bleeding":59.0,"burning":0.0,"poisoned":0.0,"carriedType":1,"carryQuantity":5,"hasItemInSlot":[false,false,false,false],"itemInSlot":[0,0,0,0]},{"previousX":19,"previousY":45,"currentX":19,"currentY":45,"isVisible":true,"myJob":0,"isExecutingAction":false,"currentActionType":24,"myName":"Boar","myType":4,"assignedHomeId":-1,"assignedWorkshopId":-1,"isMale":false,"hasHair":false,"bodyType":0,"hairType":0,"upperType":0,"facialHairType":0,"strength":1,"agility":1,"intelligence":-1,"experience":0,"learnedSkills":[],"currentStomachFill":4,"myEnergy":5,"myHealth":0,"maxHealth":60,"walkSpeed":1.2261967658996583,"bleeding":60.0,"burning":0.0,"poisoned":0.0,"carriedType":1,"carryQuantity":6,"hasItemInSlot":[false,false,false,false],"itemInSlot":[0,0,0,0]}],"tradeRoutes":[],"tradeCooldown":0.0,"isStrangerPresent":true,"stranger":{"previousX":6,"previousY":42,"currentX":6,"currentY":42,"isVisible":true,"myJob":0,"isExecutingAction":false,"currentActionType":15,"myName":"Miav","myType":0,"assignedHomeId":-1,"assignedWorkshopId":-1,"isMale":true,"hasHair":true,"bodyType":2,"hairType":2,"upperType":0,"facialHairType":2,"strength":2,"agility":1,"intelligence":2,"experience":1,"learnedSkills":[9],"currentStomachFill":4,"myEnergy":5,"myHealth":130,"maxHealth":130,"walkSpeed":1.7524113655090333,"bleeding":0.0,"burning":0.0,"poisoned":0.0,"carriedType":3,"carryQuantity":0,"hasItemInSlot":[false,false,false,false],"itemInSlot":[0,0,0,0]},"strangerType":0,"isLootDropped":true,"lootDropPos":{"x":6.969667911529541,"y":0.0,"z":42.97261428833008},"isLootSelected":false,"lootContains":3,"dropResourceInstances":[],"worldTiles":[9,9,4,8,7,5,11,11,11,9,9,2,0,6,1,8,11,3,11,8,7,8,8,11,8],"tileData":[{"cityName":"Zhapore","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":8},{"cityName":"Iantol","giveResource":10,"completion":false,"quantity":8},{"cityName":"Naggir","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":9},{"cityName":"Sragir","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":5},{"cityName":"Nagtol","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":6},{"cityName":"Srapore","giveResource":10,"completion":false,"quantity":7},{"cityName":"Ofrostan","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":9},{"cityName":"Zhastan","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":7},{"cityName":"Sinsea","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":9},{"cityName":"Ichstan","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":9},{"cityName":"Bristan","giveResource":10,"completion":false,"quantity":9},{"cityName":"Sinstan","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":6},{"cityName":"Zhara","giveResource":10,"completion":false,"quantity":6},{"cityName":"Bristan","giveResource":1,"completion":false,"quantity":8},{"cityName":"Sragir","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":8},{"cityName":"Ofrocia","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":6},{"cityName":"Sinsea","giveResource":10,"completion":false,"quantity":9},{"cityName":"Ianpore","giveResource":10,"completion":false,"quantity":6},{"cityName":"Ianra","giveResource":10,"completion":false,"quantity":9},{"cityName":"Sracia","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":7},{"cityName":"Ofrotol","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":7},{"cityName":"Sragir","giveResource":10,"completion":false,"quantity":9},{"cityName":"Ichburg","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":9},{"cityName":"Iantol","giveResource":6,"completion":false,"quantity":6},{"cityName":"Sragir","giveResource":10,"completion":false,"quantity":6}],"ships":{"x":0,"y":0,"shipPath":[],"shipType":0,"cargo":0,"crew":[]},"discovered":[true,true,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false],"questStatus":0,"titanData":{"previousX":0,"previousY":0,"currentX":0,"currentY":0,"isVisible":true,"myJob":5,"isExecutingAction":false,"currentActionType":0,"myName":"","myType":13,"assignedHomeId":-1,"assignedWorkshopId":-1,"isMale":false,"hasHair":false,"bodyType":0,"hairType":0,"upperType":0,"facialHairType":0,"strength":10,"agility":10,"intelligence":10,"experience":100,"learnedSkills":[],"currentStomachFill":0,"myEnergy":0,"myHealth":0,"maxHealth":100,"walkSpeed":1.0,"bleeding":0.0,"burning":0.0,"poisoned":0.0,"carriedType":0,"carryQuantity":0,"hasItemInSlot":[false,false,false,false],"itemInSlot":[0,0,0,0]},"isTitanSummoned":false}
```

[Более удобный вид](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbbc21a0)